# for statement and filling a list issue

Tags: python

I have a function to read a file, and fill a list with tuples of x file lines, then do something once the list have x elements, then empty this list

```
def accesslog_parser(chunk_size):
    chunk = []
    with open('access.log', 'r') as accesslog:     # Open file
        for line in accesslog:
            chunk.append(tuple(line.split()))
            if len(chunk) == chunk_size:
                print 'Printing a chunk \n'
                print chunk
                #process(chunk) # Do something with this chunk
                chunk = []            # Once processed, set empty
```

if i call the function with

```
accesslog_parser(100)
```

i get what i want, but if the last chunk < chunk_size this is out of condition and doesn't get printed

How can i fix/improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run `process(chunk)` if there is something left ...

```
def accesslog_parser(chunk_size):
    chunk = []
    with open('access.log', 'r') as accesslog:
        ...
    if chunk:
        process(chunk)
```

Comment: You're welcome, sometimes the easiest solution is the last that comes to mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is that if the chunk is bigger than 100, print the first 100 characters of the chunk, otherwise print whatever it has. Hence:

```
if len(chunk) >= chunk_size:
    print chunk[0:100]
else:
    print chunk
```